# having trouble print part of username

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
i am trying to get this working but i am not getting it print
```

def menu(choice):
    print 20 * '-','h173_37 jason proctor 12000898', 20 * '-'
    print '"a": Username'
    print '"b" : Print Exponetial'
    print '"c" : Quit'
    print 30 * '-'
    choice = raw_input("(a,b or c):")
    while choice not in ["a", "b","c"]:
        print "need a valied input "
        choice = raw_input("(a,b or c):")
    return choice

def full_name():
    full_name = raw_input("enter youer full name")
    return full_name

```
def get_first_name(full_name):

    n = (0)
    while n < len (full_name) and n != " ":
        n = n + 1
    return n

def get_last_inital(full_name):

    n = (0)
    while n > len (full_name) and n!= " ":
        n = n - 1
    return n + 1

def print_username(full_name):

    firstpart = get_first_name(full_name)
    get_first_name(full_name)== len (full_name)
    firstpart == [0,3]
    while firstpart < 3:
        firstpart+['x']
    lastpart = get_last_inital(full_name) 
    get_last_inital(full_name)== len (full_name)
    lastpart == [1,5]
    while lastpart < 5:
        lastpart+['x']

    #full_name = raw_input("enter youer full name")

    print( firstpart + lastpart + "this is your username")

#full_name()
#print_username(name)

    #def print_triangular():
        #def triangle(n):
            #return ((n**2)+2)/2.0

#n = int(raw_input('Please enter an integer: '))
#print triangle(n)


#else:

choice = 0
choice = menu(choice)    
print "You have chosen " + choice
while choice !="c":
    if choice == ("a"):
        full_name()
        def firstpart():
            firstpart()
        def lastpart ():
            lastpart()
        def print_username(full_name):
            print_username(full_name)
            username =[firstpart , lastpart]
        print "this is your username" + ("".join(firstpart , lastpart))

    #else choice ==("b"):


Pseudo code:

`get_first_name():`

 1. Set n equal to zero
 2. Loop while n is less than the length of name and the n-th character of name is not a space
 3.     Increase n by 1
 2. Return the part of name up to but not including the n-th character to the caller

`get_last_ initial():`

 1. Set n equal to the length of name minus 1
 2. While n is bigger than or equal to zero and the n-th character or name is not a space
 3. Decrease n by 1
 3. Return the part of name starting from the n+1-th character to the caller

print_username():

 1. Call get_first_name(), passing fullname, and store the first three characters in firstpart
 2. While the length of firstpart is less than three
 3.     Add an X to the end of firstpart
 4. Call get_last_name(), passing fullname, and store the first five characters in lastpart
 5. While the length of lastpart is less than five
 6.     Add an X to the end of lastpart
 7. Concatenate firstpart and lastpart, convert the resulting string to upper case and print with a helpful message

    enter code here

TypeError: join() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Comment: You don't ever call your functions.

Comment: yes in the print_username

Comment: OK, you don't ever call `print_username`, at least not in the code provided

Answer (score 0):

If you want functions in python to execute, you have to call them, for example, you could add a line

```
print_username(name)
```

to the end of the file.

Comment: i did that now i get line 19, in <module>
    get_last_inital(name)==name[1.5]
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not float

Comment: @JasonRonaldProctor: because a string index `1.5` doesn't make any sense at all. The one-and-a-halfth character? Did you not mean to use `:` instead, for a string slice?

Comment: @JasonRonaldProctor: actually, scratch that. What can you *possibly* mean with `len(name)[0.3]`? Are you [cargo-cult programming](https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) here?

Comment: it did help but i get 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' back i will try looking as to why